# Flash Builder 4.6 crashes on startup on Mac High Sierra 10.13.2

Tags: macos, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

Flash Builder 4.6 crashes on startup on my Mac running High Sierra 10.13.2.  It was running up until a few days ago, and I don't believe any upgrades have taken place on my machine since then.  Does anyone know what I should look at/change/delete?  (I cannot upgrade Flash Builder, stuck with that version due to development requirements, so please don't suggest that.)

Answer (score 0):

Your workspace may have became corrupt.

The simple test would be to try renaming your workspace directory `~/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6` to something else and try starting up Flash Builder. If that works, you can either try re-importing your project(s) or if you made a lot of customizations to the preferences, you may want to try deleting the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources\.snap` file from your old workspace and try that workspace again.

If that doesn't work, you may need to try the steps at [Keeps Crashing at Loading Workspace](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1140337) to rebuild the workspace.

I've also had where updating one of the Eclipse plugins would cause Flash Builder to lock up, but if you didn't update any of those, the workspace corruption is a very common.

Comment: I haven't updated any plugins.  I've already tried renaming my workspace directory, but he problem persists.  I've tried the steps in the link you mention, no luck with anything.  If I uninstall and reinstall Flash Builder, will I lose my license serial number?  I don't have it available to enter back in.

Comment: Reinstalling will wipe out your serial number. Can you look through ~/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.log to see what error is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Download the legacy Java 6 runtime for High Sierra https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

The error I was getting for Flash Builder 4.6 was "failed to create the java virtual machine", and this fixed it.